# Serializing tuple type - module core::tuple is private

Tags: serialization, rust

I'm going to use this code to serialize Rust tuples to the BERT format:

```
extern crate core;

pub struct Serializer;

pub trait Serialize<T> {
    fn to_bert(&self, data: T) -> Vec<u8>;
}

impl Serialize<core::tuple> for Serializer {
    fn to_bert(&self, data: core::tuple) -> Vec<u8> {
        // some implementation
    }
}
```

The Rust docs said that this type is defined in the `core::rust` module, but when I try to use this type as a parameter in a trait, the complier generates an error:

```
error: type name `core::tuple` is undefined or not in scope [E0412]
impl Serialize<core::tuple> for Serializer {
               ^~~~~~~~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0412` to see a detailed explanation
help: no candidates by the name of `tuple` found in your project; maybe you misspelled the name or forgot to import an external crate?

error: module `tuple` is private
impl Serialize<core::tuple> for Serializer {
```

If this module is private, then how can I get a defined default Rust `tuple` type and use it as a parameter of a trait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you got the name `core::tuple` originally, but it's definitely not going to help you. As the compiler tells you, it's private; you cannot use it. I don't even think `core::rust` **exists**, so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

You don't explain why you are using `libcore`, perhaps you are targeting some environment that doesn't have a memory allocator or an operating system. If that's not the case, you probably don't want to directly use `libcore`.

Beyond that, `core::tuple` is a **module**, not a **type**. You cannot use it in that position. For example:

```
fn foo(a: std::mem) {}
```

```
error: type name `std::mem` is undefined or not in scope [--explain E0412]
 --> src/main.rs:1:11
1 |> fn foo(a: std::mem) {}
  |>           ^^^^^^^^ undefined or not in scope
help: no candidates by the name of `mem` found in your project; maybe you misspelled the name or forgot to import an external crate?
```

> how can I get a defined default Rust tuple type and use it as a parameter of a trait

This doesn't completely make sense to me. If you just want something that can have a default value, then accept a generic type `T where T: Default`. Tuples implement `Default` when all of the component types implement `Default`.

If you don't mean an actual default, then you can create a new trait that means what you want and follow the same pattern.

To implement that trait for many sizes of tuples, you will likely use macros, just like the standard library does. There's no way to express the type "all tuples of arbitrary length", so macros are used to implement the trait up to some number of elements (typically 32).

I think someone else has mentioned this in the earlier questions you've asked, but you should **really** consider trying to write a BERT adapter for [serde](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde). This would allow you to focus on the new and interesting aspects and reuse the existing tested code. If nothing else, you should *read* how serde and [rustc-serialize](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustc-serialize) are implemented to see how other people have already solved the same problem.

Comment: +1 for a BERT format for Serde being the way to go. This will allow users to serialize their own structs as BERT in an easy way.